# In firefox, when right-click on a textfield, how to get the start position?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, dom

My requirement is I need to know what value is selected in a text field when right-click on the specific value portion.

e.g.  Suppose current value in the text field is "a@a.com, b@b.com, c@c.com", when I move the mouse over "b@b.com" and right click, program should know I have chosen that email address.

I already implemented it for left-click (by checking event.selectionStart), but in Firefox, right-click will not move the edit cursor to the clicked position, so wherever I right click at, the event.selectionStart keeps the same value.

Any idea? 
Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. In firefox, event.rangeOffset can be used.